# ¿Cómo indico la versión de compilador de C++ con vscode?

Tags: c++, vscode

Estoy aprendiendo c++ y se me dio por simular la función `print` de python con el siguiente código

```cpp
using namespace std;
template <class... Args>
void print(Args... args){
    ((cout << args << ' '), ...);
    cout << endl;
}
```

Esto me funciona, sin embargo en la consola me aparece un warning

```
functions/functionsPy.cpp:10:26: warning: fold-expressions only available with -std=c++1z or -std=gnu++1z
  ((cout << args << ' '), ...);
                          ^~~
```

Al parecer me dice que esta sintaxis está disponible a partir de cierta versión. Entonces como puedo especificar la versión del compilador al ejecutarlo en vscode?

Por ahora utilizo la extensión `Code Runner` para ejecutar el código, pero no sé si será la indicada dado este caso.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para poder ejecutar el código se te recomienda instalar la extensión `C/C++` de Microsoft, esta extensión ya proporciona una forma de compilar el código. Este compilado se lleva a cabo mediante un comando que se encuentra en un archivo de configuración. En la [guía de vscode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw) que se proporciona cuando comienzas en C o C++ se te indica los pasos para crear este archivo de configuración, los cuales también te diré aquí.

La forma de especificar el argumento sería de la forma `C:\MinGW\bin\g++.exe -g "ruta\de\archivo\archivo.cpp" -std=c++17` pero como usas una extensión este trabajo es automatizado por esta, por eso veremos los pasos para configurar la extensión correctamente.

Primero necesitamos crear una carpeta llamada `.vscode` donde irá los archivos de configuración.  Luego, se debe crear un archivo llamado `task.json` en el que irá algunos comandos de compilación. Muy probablemente ya tengas esta carpeta y este archivo, así que solo ajusta o agrega lo que necesitas.

La estructura debe ser mas o menos así:

```json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: gcc.exe compilar archivo activo",
            "command": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind":"build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "compilador: C:\\MinGW\\bin\\g++.exe"
        }
    ]
}
```

Recuerda que debes de colocar la ruta en donde tengas tu ejecutable.
Lo que debes de cambiar es la parte de `args` en `tasks`, donde deberás agregar otro argumento en el que se indique la versión del compilador que deseas utilizar, quedando así:

```json
...
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
                "-std=c++17"
            ],
...
```

Con esto ya estaría todo, ahora ya puedes compilar tu archivo usando la versión `c++17` usando la extensión por defecto `C/C++`.

Para el caso de `Code Runner` el proceso sería lo mismo, solo nos dirigimos a la configuración de la extensión, que de igual manera será un `.json`. Ten cuidado aquí, ya que la extensión tiene diferentes configuraciones, donde puedes hacer una configuración general, del espacio de trabajo o  de un proyecto en el que trabajes, realiza la modificación en el ámbito que creas necesario.

Una vez ubicado en el archivo debes ubicar la sección `code-runner.executorMap`, si no existe la puedes crear pero deja que el autocompletado la genere, ya que esta sección incluye todos los comandos para la compilación y ejecución de distintos archivos en distintos lenguajes.

Luego de que la hayas ubicado o creado lo anterior busca ahora la extensión `cpp`, por ejemplo aquí se encuentra luego de `c`:

```json
{
    "folders": [
        {
            "path": "ruta\de\tu\proyecto\o\folder"
        }
    ],
    "settings": {
        "files.associations": {
            ...
        },
        "code-runner.clearPreviousOutput": true,
        "code-runner.executorMap": {
            "javascript": "node",
            "java": "cd $dir && javac $fileName && java $fileNameWithoutExt",
            "c": "cd $dir && gcc $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
            "cpp": "cd $dir && g++ $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
            "php": "php",
            "python": "python -u",
            ...
        }
    },
    ...
}
```

Deberás editar el comando de compilación agregando el argumento que especifica la versión del compilador, por ejemplo quedaría:

```json
"cpp": "cd $dir && g++ $fileName -std=c++17 -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
```

Con esto ya estaría configurado `Code Runner` para poder usar la versión `c++17` al compilar tu código :D.